# Migrate GWT 2.0.4 Project to GWT 2.1.0

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I update my Google Plugin (and GWT) version from 2.0.4 to 2.1.0

There are now some warnings for deprecated function that I will fix, but the problem for me is this warning:

```
The file war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-servlet.jar has a different size than GWT SDK library gwt-servlet.jar; perhaps it is a different version?
```

Is it OK just to override this jar file with new one from

```
eclipse\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.1.0_2.1.0.v201010280102\gwt-2.1.0
```

directory

and what about other files in war directory that are not manualy created by me? (images, html files, js files, and gwt subdirectory)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same problem.

You can either overwrite it or remove it. If you remove it, eclipse will copy automatically the new library.

Just in case, if you also get some weird crashes after upgrading to GWT 2.1, try moving the GWT library to the first place of the BuildPath ;)

Comment: Which other files? The only file from GWT you need is gwt-servlet.jar

Comment: I think he means all the "other files in war directory". I just leave them and uncheck the "Use GWT" box in the project settings, then recheck it and let the plugin do its stuff.

Comment: I tried deleting the gwt-servlet.jar file from /war/WEB-INF/lib, and Eclipse didn't recreate it for me. What I did to fix it from that point was to go to Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit then uncheck the checkbox "Use Google Web Toolkit". Then I pressed OK, and repeated the steps, but this time I checked the "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox, and the gwt-servlet.jar file was indeed recreated in war/WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 12):

What I did to fix it was to just delete the gwt-servlet.jar file from /war/WEB-INF/lib. In my case, Eclipse didn't recreate it for me, and instead gave me an error message saying that the file could not be found.

What I did to fix it from this point was to go to Project > Properties > Google > Web Toolkit then uncheck the checkbox "Use Google Web Toolkit", then I pressed OK to confirm the change.

Then I repeated the steps, but this time I checked the "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox, and the gwt-servlet.jar file was indeed recreated in war/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: In my case, after I deleted the gwt-servlet.jar file, I used quick fix to tell Eclipse to recreate it for me. (Note: This was for GWT 2.7.0 and Eclipse 4.4).

Answer (score 0):

For `GWT-2.4.0`, I have used the following page and their instruction.

> Go to the WEB-INF/lib directory on ecipse, right click on it, and choose "Build Path > use as source folder".

Source : [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/geogebra-dev/ACzHZwu3IVU/ZKn1brRVDQAJ)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using eclipse quick-fix.
Works well for me, it will automatically find the right jar file. Hope it helps. ^^